# C++ Expected a type specifier (regex)

Tags: c++, regex, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

class Parser {
protected:
    // regex: containers
    static const regex rxProc("procedure\s+([\w]+)\s*{");
}
```

I am getting an error for the `"procedure\s+([\w]+)\s*{"` part. Expected a type specifier. I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to link the regexp library that you're using... the compiler thinks it's a function definition rather than a call

Comment: I updated the code in qn. I do have the includes I think I need. It works if they are declared as local variables in functions, but not in the class, why?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Not at all. If the error message is "Expected a type specifier", then it hasn't at all reached linkage. Please read a paper on how compiling C-style languages works.

Comment: Note that you need to escape "\"! This should be rxProc("procedure\\s+([\\w]+)\\s*{").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the other answers here to understand what are you actually asking the compiler. If you are trying to make a constant inside your class - I provide a solution here.

Using static members in C++ is fun, but only for POD (plain-old-data) members. For more complex members things get ugly. Even for `char*` this does not scale up. Using good old C `#define`s is sometimes a good idea - even in C++;

Something like this will fix your compilation problem. Play with the `#if 0` to trigger your old code, and compile using `g++ -std=gnu++0x  -c test1.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

#if 0
// my fix

// in your H file
class Parser {
protected:
    // regex: containers
    static const regex rxProc;
};    
// in your CPP file
const regex Parser::rxProc = regex("procedure\\s+([\\w]+)\\s*{");
#else

// your old code
class Parser {
protected:
    // regex: containers
    static const regex rxProc("procedure\\s+([\\w]+)\\s*{");
};
#endif
```

*(not even getting into the issue of using regex to define a syntax tree... or parsing a Pascal file... which is just bad idea and will break oh, so, many times... just don't)*

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks you are declaring a static function `rxProc` returning `const regex` and accepting one parameter of type.... and then he cannot get what type should it be.

Comment: I see a downvote but without a comment. Is my explanation incorrect or something?

Comment: Apart from just being a bit incomplete (not providing any solution)? No, I don't think so (but haven't downvoted it anyway).